# Seeking System Requirements of GME for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.4, gme, system-requirements

I've been trying to install GME 0.7.4 without success. This version is designed to run with ArcGIS 10.3 but I have installed ArcGIS 10.4.

Does anyone know if ArcGIS 10.4 is compatible (or can be made to be compatible) with GME 0.7.4?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please [edit] your question to expand on "without success" - what is it doing or not doing?  Are you able to install the tools?  Are you unable to use them?  Is it specific tools that aren't working, or all of them?  Have you tried contacting the author as per [this page](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmehelp.htm)?  What was the result?

Comment: IMO this question is fine, "Is GME 0.7.4 compatible with ArcGIS 10.4" is an answerable question.

Comment: I do not think it is compatible I get a notification that "The application requires that assembly ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase Version 10.3.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.  I think the only thing you can do is wait for a new version of GME to come out that supports 10.4

Answer (score 1):

The [Acquiring and Installing GME](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm) page says:

> This page contains the information you need to determine if GME is
>   comptabale [sic] with your version of ArcGIS, the link to the GME installer,
>   and installation instructions.

The most recent ArcGIS Desktop version listed is 10.3 and you are using 10.4 which suggests GME is not compatible with your version.

If the page needs updating/re-confirming then I think you should contact [Spatial Ecology](http://www.spatialecology.com/) who are the developers of GME.